# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, rollup

I am exploring making a component library using React and rollup. I'm finding that the app that is consuming the library is bundling it in the wrong order.

This is causing the below error:

```
bundle.js:99 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime'
    at webpackMissingModule (bundle.js:99)
    at Module.../../../component-library/dist/index.es.js
```

In the Webpack CLI I also get similar errors:

```
ERROR in /.../component-library/dist/index.es.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/.../component-library/dist'
 @ /.../component-library/dist/index.es.js 2:0-33 68:18-26
 @ ./src/App/index.jsx
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in /.../component-library/dist/index.es.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in '/.../component-library/dist'
 @ /...component-library/dist/index.es.js 1:0-41 74:22-26
 @ ./src/App/index.jsx
 @ ./src/index.js
```

I have not published the library anywhere, so just using `yarn link` for now.

In my component library, my rollup config looks like:

```js
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external"
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel"
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs"
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve"
const packageJson = require("./package.json")

const config = [
  {
    input: "./src/index.js",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    external: Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies || {}),
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      babel({ exclude: "node_modules/**", babelHelpers: "bundled" }),
    ],
  },
]

export default config
```

My babel config

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [["@babel/preset-env"], ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }]],
}
```

My package.json

```json
{
  "name": "component-library",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A component library.",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/.../component-library.git",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "rollup -c --watch",
    "build": "rollup -c"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.2.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^5.0.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.10.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "rollup": "^2.38.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0"
  }
}
```

I can see the code that is output by rollup looks like it is correct:

```js
import { jsxs } from 'react/jsx-runtime';
import { useState } from 'react';

function _slicedToArray(arr, i) {
  return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _unsupportedIterableToArray(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest();
}

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr;
}

//continue...
```

In the bundle that my app's Webpack outputs, it adds the code for the component right near at the top, before any dependencies such as React or the actual app code.

```
line 76: //prior bundled code...
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./src/index.js");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "../../../component-library/dist/index.es.js":
/*!*******************************************************************!*\
  !*** /.../component-library/dist/index.es.js ***!
  \*******************************************************************/
/*! exports provided: Example */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "Example", function() { return Example; });
!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }());
!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'react'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }());

function _slicedToArray(arr, i) {
  return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _unsupportedIterableToArray(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest();
}

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr;
}

//continue...

//react/jsx-runtime is set up on line 118391
```

No matter where I add the component in the App, the code is bundled in the same place. I also tried to include React in my rollup bundle from the library. However, then my app complains about multiple React versions being loaded.

I am not too sure what to try next. I haven't experienced this with any other libraries I have downloaded via npm and used in my app. So this is making me think there is something wrong with my rollup config or build process.

Comment: I also got the same error in WebStorm. I just did `Invalidate Caches & Restart`. (Posting this not as an answer, if someone get in here with same problem, they can seen this).

Comment: resolved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76561254/6318705

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So my setup actually was working. There was somehow a glitch in the symlink. I as able to resolve by running `yarn unlink` and `yarn link`. The package is now bundling correctly.

Answer (score 32):

This solution resolved my issue. I found it over [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-module-not-found-cant-resolve-react-jsx-runtime)

> ##### ️ with NPM
>
> ```
> npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
> ```
>
> ##### ️ ONLY If you use TypeScript
>
> ```
> npm install --save-dev @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest
> ```
>
> ##### ----------------------------------------------
>
> ##### ️ with YARN
>
> ```
> yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest
> ```
>
> ##### ️ ONLY If you use TypeScript
>
> ```
> yarn add @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest --dev
> ```

Comment: is there a way to resolve the issue without upgrading react? i am using react 16

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar error and the problem was that I had forgotten to run `npm install`

Comment: I was using docker and VSCode was complaining, `npm i` fixed it

Answer (score 9):

This did it for me!

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm i
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this error was fixed by updating `babel.config.json`. In `presets` array I changed runtime to `classic` instead of  `automatic`

```
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "classic" // changed automatic to classic
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello I got the same error when I tried to add the graphql playground using `graphiql` in my `docusaurus` documentation

```js
import React from "react";
import { createGraphiQLFetcher } from "@graphiql/toolkit";
import { GraphiQL } from "graphiql";
import "graphiql/graphiql.css";

const fetcher = createGraphiQLFetcher({
  url: "https://my.graphql.api/graphql",
});

export default function GraphqlPlayGround() {
  return <GraphiQL fetcher={fetcher} />;
}
```

I was running into this issue

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in '/Users/user/Desktop/Saleor/DocAuth0/node_modules/@graphiql/react/dist'
Did you mean 'jsx-runtime.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'react/jsx-runtime' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

To fix this you need to create a custom loader for you `webpack` configuration to disable this behaviour

> Since webpack 5.0.0-beta.30, you're required to specify extensions when using imports in .mjs files or any .js files with a package.json with "type": "module". You can still disable the behavior with resolve.fullySpecified set to false if you see any related errors in your project.

The steps you need to follow for this process are:

1. Create plugins folder: Create a plugins folder at your project root.
2. Create a plugin: Create a plugin (e.g., `my-loaders`) inside the plugins folder with `index.js` and package.json files:

> As noted in the Docusaurus docs for `configureWebpack()`, the return object highlighted below gets merged into the final `webpack` config.

`/plugins/my-loaders/index.js`

```js
module.exports = function (context, options) {
  return {
    name: 'my-loaders',
    configureWebpack(config, isServer) {
      return {
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.m?js/,
              resolve: {
                fullySpecified: false
              }
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    },
  };
};
```

`/plugins/my-loaders/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "my-loaders",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true
}
```

3.Update Docusaurus config: Update your Docusaurus configuration file to use the plugin:
`/docusaurus.config.js`

```json
plugins: [
  // ...
  'my-loaders'
  // ...
]
```

4.Update project dependency list to use plugin: Specify the plugin as a dependency in the package.json at your project root:
`/package.json`

```js
{
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "my-loaders": "file:plugins/my-loaders",
    // ...
  },
    // ...
}
```

5.Install new plugin dependency for project: Execute the following to make use of the new plugin in your project:

```bash
npm i
```

Reference:
Please follow up [this documentaion] for more details (https://dwf.dev/blog/2022/11/12/2022/updating-docusaurus-webpack-config)

Answer (score 1):

Updating your react version possibily can resolve your problem. Command line: npm install --save react@latest.

If you wish to specific a version, you need to run: npm install --save react@ e.g. npm install --save react@17.0.2

Comment: They were using yarn—not npm

Comment: @Moctar Why updating to latest solves issue ?

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime'

### Solution

1. Update your version of react and / or react-dom

   `npm install react@latest react-dom@latest`
2. If using TypeScript, update the types files

   `npm install @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest`

Answer (score 0):

for me it was just an issue because I'm using Linux subsystem for windows with pnpm.

so in my `node_modules/.modules.yaml` i needed to change

```
#storeDir: /mnt/d/.pnpm-store/v3 # from this
storeDir: D:\.pnpm-store\v3 # to this
```

I think webstorm\vs code should understand both of them... but I am too last to open an issue for this.

**update:** actually, this does not always work, just use normal windows terminal when installing with pnpm

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was missing .js in my webpack config's resolve.extensions.

I know OP is using rollup but for webpack users running into the same issue. :)

I'm currently doing a project with typescript, react, webpack and babel-loader.

I didn't have any source js files so I thought do I really need .js in the resolve.extensions array in my webpack config?

Then I started encountering the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in
> '/home/tylerbreau/repos/portfolio/src/views/app'  @
> ./src/views/index.tsx 4:0-53 7:30-41

I ended looking at the react folder in my node_modules and saw that it does have a jsx-runtime.js file. I tried adding it the .js back to webpack's resolve.extensions and the error disappeared.

In hindsight I guess this make senses.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you encounter this issue while developing on vscode using Linux subsystem for windows and pnpm.
Ensure you download the following extension https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development then open the folder again on WSL.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error after setting up the project with **vite** on my **subsystem for Linux**, and none of the solutions up there worked for me. But after shifting on windows, the error disappeared. I still wonder why? Anyways, If you have the same issue and are on **WSL**, consider setting the project on **windows**.

Answer (score -1):

**Just copy component's source code into your project is a hack way.**
if you can't resolve this problem, try this.
I can't resolve this error by any way I could find. Beside, update react version is unsafe to a big project, it may course a lot of test and unknown error.
:) love and peace.

Answer (score -2):

Just upgrade the version of your react application.
Check the version of react and typescript .Even I was facing same issue .When I upgraded to latest version my application was not showing any error.

For more information check the given link.
https://betterprogramming.pub/upgrade-create-react-app-based-projects-to-version-4-cra-4-d7962aee11a6

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31422769)

Answer (score -2):

I have resolve this issue.

May you are using old version of reactjs, Don't need to update that. Just do following:

- Copy jsx-dev-runtime.js , jsx-runtime and cjs folder from the lastest **react** (lastest) present in node_modules
- Paste these in **react** folder present in node_modules where the error occur.

Let me know it work or not!

Thank you!

Comment: this will only work locally, not on the server when all dependencies are installed automatically by npm install. Or you would have to create a script that does the same change on the server during each build.

Answer (score -7):

yarn add react-transition-group@1.x

Comment: Please add more details. How this is helpful, how this is related to OP`s question and how it solves the problem.