# Cannot find the right `jsx` configuration without errors for react typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, module, jsx

I am working on a react project, with react 17.0.2, and typescript 4.3.5.  I just added a new external package that is causing problems.  When trying to import components from this new package, I get the error `Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' error while use try to create the shared component with storybook in react-typescript`.  This error is well discussed in [this question here](Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' error while use try to create the shared component with storybook in react-typescript).  The solution seems to suggest that the `jsx` property withing the tsconfig `compilerOptions` may be the problem.  Mine is currently:

```
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
```

When I change it to just `"jsx": "react"`, I get the familiar `'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)` error, which is well discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656055/react-refers-to-a-umd-global-but-the-current-file-is-a-module).

I cannot upgrade react (yet) for this project.  I tried upgrading typescript tp @^5, but that did not make a difference.  I tried several other options for `jsx` in the tsconig (i.e. `preserve`, `react-jsxdev`), also with no change.  I also tried several custom webpack solutions from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913201/uncaught-error-cannot-find-module-react-jsx-runtime), also with no change.  (I'm using CRACO to customize a create-react-app setup).

I feel as though I am stuck between a rock and a hard place.  **What is the correct config to help me avoid these `Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' error while use try to create the shared component with storybook in react-typescript` errors?**

For reference here is the full error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@company/component-library/index.js 1:0-56
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in '/Users/slutske/Desktop/project/node_modules/@company/component-library'
Did you mean 'jsx-runtime.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'react/jsx-runtime' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

Sure enough when I look into the source code within node_modules for this package, I see imports that look like this:

```js
import { __rest, __assign } from '../_virtual/_tslib.js';
import { jsxs, jsx } from 'react/jsx-runtime';
```

And my full tsconfig:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "es2021"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node",
      "cypress",
      "cypress-file-upload",
      "@types/wicg-file-system-access"
    ],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types/wicg-file-system-access"],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".eslintrc"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.{ts,tsx}",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```