# Typescript Errors on new Vite React Project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I created a new Vite Typescript + SWC React project via: `yarn create vite@latest my-app-name`.

Afterwards, I installed the dependencies with `yarn`.

When viewing the default boilerplate, such as `main.tsx`, I get a lot of TS errors, for instance:

`Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)` when hovering over `<React.StrictMode>`

or

`Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)` when hovering over `<App />`.

I tried adding typings via `yarn add @types/react -D`, confirming it was in my dev dependencies, restarting my TS server, restarting VSCode, restarting the dev server, and confirming I have `"jsx": "react-jsx"` in my `tsconfig`, but I still have these errors.

How can I fix these Typescript issues?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913201/uncaught-error-cannot-find-module-react-jsx-runtime)

Comment: What code editor are you using? Vscode? Neovim? Also, don't add `@latest` when creating your project.

Comment: I am using VSCode. Why not use @latest? I ended up fixing the issue by restarting with `npm` over `yarn` also.